Wiring a 240v GFCI Breaker for NEMA 6-20R
I'm working on wiring up my new workshop. I've done a good amount of DIY electrical work before but I've never wired up a 240v receptacle like this before that doesn't have a neutral (NEMA 6-20R).
From what I understand, it should be as simple as wiring up the two hot wires to the two hot terminals on the receptacle, and of course connecting ground. On the breaker (240v, 20A GFCI - made by GE) side, you also hook up the pigtail to the neutral bar, and don't do anything with the neutral terminal on the breaker. Makes sense.
However, right after I got done hooking everything up, I switched the main breaker back on and the GFCI breaker immediately trips. I double checked the wiring, and I literally just ran this Romex so as far as I can tell it's not damaged. So what gives? Could it just be a bad breaker? It's late and I'm already done for the day but I'm going to take my multimeter and outlet tester out tomorrow morning and see if I can tell what might be going on.



Does the breaker indicate whether this is a GFCI trip vs. an overcurrent trip?

I don't see why it should trip, but be sure to mark the white as a hot, see NEC 200.7(C) https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#200.7_(C)

disconnect the romex from the breaker and check for short-circuits (if you can, perform an insulation test).

If you reset the breaker, does it immediately trip again? Or does it only trip when you toggle the main breaker?

It's not an uncommon thing for a GFCI device to trip when first powered up. By design.
The important question is what happens when you reset it.
As already commented you need to mark the hot white conductor.

This was actually what it was and I felt quite silly after figuring it out...I was aware that GFCIs do this as I've installed others and I could have sworn I already hit the reset...but once I hit it the second time, no more problems.
